# Output csharp into a html class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to acheive outputing a variable from csharp into the class of a html element.

Currently i'm doing this:

```
 @foreach (var cocktail in Model)
{



    <li>
        <div class="drink">
            <div class="drink-sprite " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="name">@cocktail.CocktailName</div>
            <div class="price">£@cocktail.Price.ToString("0.00")</div>
            <div class="description">@cocktail.Description</div>
        </div>
    </li>

}
```

essentially in the div class="drink-sprite" I want to put the drink type in the glass so an image is shown based on the class types. so drink-sprite martini - which is dervied from cocktail.type.

Anythoughts?

Comment: `<div class="drink-sprite @cocktail.Type" ></div>`?

Comment: Is `cocktail.Type` a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var cocktail in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="drink">
            <div class="drink-sprite @cocktail.Type"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="name">@cocktail.CocktailName</div>
            <div class="price">£@cocktail.Price.ToString("0.00")</div>
            <div class="description">@cocktail.Description</div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: was my mistake - i tried that and it didn't work but was because Im saving the type as an integer - now i need to find a way to look up the id against another table and input the name.

Comment: I think you can create new readonly property in your model.

Like This.

public string CoctailTypeString
{
  get
  {
     if(CoctailType == 1)
     {
         return "Martini";
     }
  }
}

Comment: I already have a database with this in so need to try and retreive this from there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just print the variable directly in the `class` declaration?

Like so:

```
<div class="drink-sprite @cocktail.Type" ></div>
```

This should output the `cocktail.Type` directly into the HTML as you'd need.

If `cocktail.Type` is `null` or `""` (empty), then this will still work, and won't affect your current implementation.